# Tutorial info to create a device with bluetooth and fetch data on a smart phone

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I want to learn how to:

1. create a device with a bluetooth chip, that would transmit the information to the smart phone it is connected to.
2. How to code, and fetch the information from a device with bluetooth.

Please let me know where I should read about it, and learn.

Basically, I am looking for tutorials to learn how to create a fitness band sort of a project.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562875/android-bluetooth-example

Comment: he is not asking for only phone side example, he asks for create a device and interface with it, no duplicate

Comment: Basically I am looking for a tutorial to create a fitness band sort of a project. - will add the same in my question as well.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend getting an arduino and the BLE shield from [redbear](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/)

also get a [sensor tag](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag2015/index.html?DCMP=ep-mcu-lpad-mfba15-en&HQS=ep-mcu-lpad-mfba15-lydesign-20150413-lp-sensortag-en) from TI

And a BLE sniffer for good debugging

They have all the info on the hardware and phone interface Good luck!